# symfony collection returns empty files

Tags: file, symfony, input, collections

I have a form with collection

```
class EventType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('header', TextType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']])
                ->add('text', TextareaType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '3']])
                ->add('fileNames', CollectionType::class, [
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label' => false,
                    'entry_type' => EventFileType::class,
                    ])
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Post',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'btn btn-success',
                        'style' => 'margin-top: 10px;'
                        ]
                    ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Event::class,
            'csrf_token_id' => 'eventToken',
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
        ]);
    }
}
```

here is entry type for collection

```
class EventFileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fileName', FileType::class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'csrf_token_id' => 'eventFiles',
        ));
    }
}
```

and my form looks like:

```
 {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'form_create_event'}}) }}

                        <ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.fileNames.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                        </ul>
                        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

with js adding fields. and ajax:

```
.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{ path('event_create') }}',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                data: new FormData(this),
```

so I get text inputs and $_FILE is not empty. `$form['fileNames']->getData()` will show files but with empty fields, so if I input 2 files will be : `[{"fileName":{}},{"fileName":{}}]`, one file - `[{"fileName":{}}]`, more than 3 files says and form will be invalid. So how exactly do I make my form get these files? (I don't map them) and how can I get as many files as I want?